# How to put a border around an ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, border, itemscontrol

I have an itemscontrol with a custom panel inside a usercontrol. The usercontrols size is only constrained by the parent window size.

```
<UserControl>
  <Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="5">
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveGame.Grid.CellsFlat}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Wpf:HexagonalPanel/>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Button />
          </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I now want the border to be drawn only around the resulting panel.
But instead its drawn around the whole grid or probably more precisely at the same size as the grid.

I think I implemented the MeasureOverride correctly on my HexagonalPanel, it returns the correct size, so shouldn't it draw the border at that size?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't set a size on the `ItemsControl`, so it will be sized to its parent too. Try setting the `ItemsControl`'s `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Center`; that will make the `ItemsControl`'s actual size match that of its content.

Comment: thanks! it worked!
I still have to learn a lot about WPF layout system

Comment: I hear ya. It takes some getting used to.

Answer (score 5):

`ItemsControl` itself has `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` properties. You probably want to be using those since `ItemsControl` has a `Border` in its `ControlTemplate` by default.

Answer (score 0):

you can achive this,calculating and updating new size value:

```
public class MyPanel : Panel{
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize){

// calculate new size
........

 this.SetValue(WidthProperty, totalwidth);
  this.SetValue(HeightProperty, totalheight);

return new Size(totalwidth, totalheight);
}
}
```